# Use C++ variables inside System("");

Tags: c++, cmd

Is there a way to use variables inside the command: system("...");? For example, I tried this but it didn't work:

```
int main ()
{
    int x=5;
    system("echo Number " x " is my favorite number.");
    return 0;
}
```

I also tried this

```
system("echo Number " << x << " is my favorite number.");
```

And it didn't work as well.
Thank you.

Note: I just started learing C++ im still a beginner.

Comment: You need some a `std::string`.

Comment: @iBug i tried it. It didnt work

Comment: `i tried it. It didnt work` Please show how you tried it

Comment: @KillzoneKid he edited the comment, he was saying something else. I dont know how to use std::string

Comment: @EvilDEvil When comment is edited you could see little pencil next to it.

Comment: @KillzoneKid maybe he deleted it and wrote another one, I don't know im new to this website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C++11, there's a handy `std::to_string` for you:

```
std::string part_a("echo Number "), part_b(" is my favorite number");
system((part_a + std::to_string(x) + part_b).c_str());
```

This calls the overloaded `operator+()` for `class basic_string`.

The traditional way is to print it into a `std::stringstream` and use the underlying string.

Comment: You two guys are so fast! I just realized it.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I used Dev-C++ and it didn't. I also tried online compiler and still didn't work. What program did you use?

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thank you.